Is Vuforia compatible in Unity 6 LTS?
https://developer.vuforia.com/library/platform-support/supported-versions
While Unity 2022 LTS is the listed supported version, I briefly tested using the AR Camera in Unity 6, which seemed to work.
I wonder however if it is fully compatible to use it Unity 6. Unity 2022 says to be supported until at least May 2025, and since I need use another unity package that is compatible with Unity 2020 (so requires code changes to make it work on 2022/Unity 6) we were thinking to stick with latest LTS release there is currently.
Anybody aware if there are currently any issues in using Vuforia on Unity 6?
Tried on Unity 6 and AR Camera works.

Sounds like something to rather ask the authors of Vuforia tbh ...
